# Firebird entity framework errow while generate model from database

Tags: entity-framework, firebird

I had to import data from firebird database to Entity Framework, in order to do so I'v installed .net provider and DDEX Provider for visual studio.
My problem occurs when I was adding any table to model the erros says

`"Key Part: 'SomeColumn' for type MyTable is not valid. All parts of the key must be non nullable.**"`

It does't matter if I'am trying to import one table or many tables, I always had the same error. 
What I have to do ? 
Any Ideas ? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on your tables?

Comment: Yes I have one. 
Buy I solved my problem.

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me, if you have a primary key, it shouldn't try to use the entire table as a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem.
All I need to do is **right click on model.edmx ->Open with ->XML Text Editor** and remove all  but one which is appropiate ID of table.

Comment: I can't get to see the entity on the XML view, it looks like EF didn't write the XML code on de model.edmx. Any help here?